# Compiler not throwing error when its supposed to

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw

I saw this example at cppreference, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template:

```
namespace N 
{
    template<class T> 
    class Y // template definition
    { 
        void mf() {} 
    }; 
}
 
// template class Y<int>; // error: class template Y not visible in the global namespace
using N::Y;
// template class Y<int>; // error: explicit instantiation outside 
                          // of the namespace of the template
```

I assume they mean that even after declaring "using N::Y", the line "template class Y;" would lead to error.
I tested this in vscode using the code below, but no error occurred and "code is finished" was printed.

```
#include <iostream>
namespace N 
{
    template<class T> 
    class Y // template definition
    { 
        void mf() {} 
    }; 
}
 
using N::Y;
template class Y<int>;

int main () {

    N::Y<int> a;
    std::cout<<"code is finished"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I then tested the exact code using leetcode playground, and the error occurred:
`Finished in N/A Line 12: Char 16: error: explicit instantiation of 'N::Y' must occur in namespace 'N' template class Y<int>; ^ Line 5: Char 11: note: explicit instantiation refers here class Y // template definition ^ 1 error generated.`

Is this occurring because I installed c++ wrong? I remember having huge troubles trying to install c++ on windows because there seemed to be no official website to get it from (for java I got it easily from oracle). I've forgotten how I installed it or where I installed it from, but perhaps this could be helpful:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.469]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\zhou9>g++ --version
g++ (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: No error here either: [https://ideone.com/8Q1VyX](https://ideone.com/8Q1VyX)

Comment: ***Is this occurring because I installed c++ wrong?*** Unlikely. Although you have not updated msys2 as there is a newer version of MinGW.

Comment: @drescherjm add `-pedantic`

Comment: @drescherjm even when I added the line "N::Y<int> a;" in main so Y is actually used, the same thing happens.

Comment: I just saw that on compilerexplorer. I needed to add `-pedantic` to get an error.

Comment: ***and still crashes in leetcode playground.*** As we have discovered there are likely different compiler settings used and that caused warnings to be treated as errors.

Comment: @drescherjm Which one is the "standard" compiler setting that I should set to then, and how can I change my compiler setting to that? I'm sorry for being a bit clueless, but I also don't know what "add -pedantic" means, where to add it, and how adding it gets me an error.

Comment: See the difference here: [https://godbolt.org/z/5h7P7vedf](https://godbolt.org/z/5h7P7vedf) the first pane added `-std=c++14 -Wall -Werror -pedantic` options. The second used the default settings which compiled fine while the first shows the error.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm quite new to c++ so I never used the website before, but when it says "cc1plus.exe: all warnings being treated as errors", is it saying that the compiler setup for leetcode playground is treating warnings as errors, while mine doesn't --- leading to errors?

Comment: Yes, that is basically the reason for the difference.

Comment: I see. I'm not familiar with cpp conventions, but does this mean that I should also find some way to change my compiler settings so it also throw this error? Or should I just leave it as it is?

Comment: If you add `-std=c++14 -Wall -Werror -pedantic` to your compiler options that you typed when you compiled from the command line or as additional arguments in your VSCode `tasks.json` you can get the same output.

Comment: Saying _"trouble trying to install C++ on Windows"_ doesn't make the same sense as would be _"trouble trying to install Java on Windows"_, because, while Java is also a platform (and a product sold by Oracle), C++ is not a platform and not a product. C++ is only a programming language; it has an official ISO standard, but no "official" implementation. You can download and install many different competing C++ compilers (such as Clang, GCC, MSVC), and many different competing integrated development environments (IDEs, such as Code::Blocks, C++Builder, MS Visual Studio Code, MS Visual Studio).

Comment: Also, a nitpick regarding terminology: we don't usually say that a C++ compiler _"throws an error"_, it's better to say that the compiler _"**generates** an error"_ (or _"produces an error"_), or that something in the source code _"results in a compilation error"_, for example. But _"to throw"_ something has a different meaning, which is usually reserved for describing exceptions (like in `try` … `catch` and `throw`ing of an `std::exception` or something).

Comment: @heapunderrun Ah, I see! That's why all the websites to download cpp from looks "unofficial" and feels sketchy. I always thought there's a standard, formalized compiler that everyone uses, but apparently not.

Comment: There are companies that produce "professional" versions of C++, but an amazing amount of C++ work, maybe even most, is done on compilers produced by volunteers. It's pretty cool.

Comment: General note: Whatever compiler you use, crank up the warnings. Compiler errors mean the source code cannot be transformed into runnable code. Compiler warnings mean the code can be transformed into something that runs, but odds are pretty good that it doesn't do what you want. If the compiler can point out a logical mistake, that's time saved debugging.